# Php preg_match_all, wordpress function

Tags: php, preg-match-all

I have found this code on internet...i'm really don't know about php...
can someone tech me,pleasee..

```
<?php
function catch_that_image() {
  global $post, $posts;
  $first_img = '';
  ob_start();
  ob_end_clean();
  $output = preg_match_all('<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>', $post->post_content, $matches);
  $first_img = $matches [1] [0];

  if(empty($first_img)){ //Defines a default image
    $first_img = "/images/default.jpg";
  }
  return $first_img;
}
?>
```

How to replace `<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>`

if i want take word after "=" and before "]" 
with this text:

```
[image name=ubuntustudio-tribal-54] 
or
[image name=office-tool]
or 
[image name=car] 
or 
[image name=158]
```

i  want the output TAKE "a-z or symbol or number" AFTER THIS "=" and BEFORE THIS "]"

Thanks

Comment: What about teaching yourself?

Comment: Not sure I get it. Are your images shortcodes or what's going on? Why would you have images wrapped in brackets in the post_content? If it's proper HTML, I suggest using DOMDocument, and not regex.

Comment: when i don't have the skill to do a task, i hire some one.

Comment: yes adeneo,i'm using image shortcode in post_content...and DOMDocument,i don't understand this coding....can you help me with this code?

Comment: why are you using code you don't understand?

Comment: sgroves,i still learning php...i just want to understand how this work:<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>  i want to replace this code so this code can catch this [image name=car] ,maybe like name[*=][]$] word/number/symbol start at = and befor ]

Comment: so go learn about regexes. then you'll understand it. there's no other way to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you found on the internet is kind of irrelevant. In order to achieve what you want you need something like this:

```
$str = "[image name=ubuntustudio-tribal-54] ";
$pat = "~\[image name=([^\]]+)~i";
preg_match($pat, $str, $matches);
$name = $matches[1];
```

After that `$name` would be bound to `ubuntustudio-tribal-54`.

See the docs for more details regarding PHP's [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php).
See also, this great source of info about [Regular Expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) in general.

Comment: not sure why you're escaping twice `\\[` but in PCRE for PHP you only have to escape once: `\[`

Comment: thanks expert system..i made this     `<?php
function catch_that_image() {
  global $post, $posts;
  $first_img = '';
$str = "[image name=ubuntustudio-tribal-54] ";
$pat = "~\\[image name=([^\\]]+)~i";
  ob_start();
  ob_end_clean();
  $output = preg_match($pat, $str, $matches);

$name = $matches[1];

  if(empty($first_img)){ //Defines a default image
    $first_img = "/images/default.jpg";
  }
  return $name;
}
?>`      but how to replace $str = "[image name=ubuntustudio-tribal-54] ";
so,this str get the code from wordpress post?

Comment: @ HamZa DzCyberDeV True, in PCRE for PHP you only have to escape once - I am used to the double-escaping from Java :) I am going to remove the double escaping from my answer asap. Thx for pointing out !

Comment: @Ari Riko My code was just an illustration. I cannot answer with certainty how you should implement it in your specific scenario, because I do not know your code. Maybe something like this would work for you: `<?php
function catch_that_image() {
  global $post, $posts;
  $first_img = '';
  ob_start();
  ob_end_clean();
  preg_match("~\[image name=([^\]]+)~i", $post->post_content, $matches);
  $first_img = $matches[1];

  if(empty($first_img)){ //Defines a default image
    $first_img = "/images/default.jpg";
  }
  return $first_img;
}
?>`

Comment: @ExpertSystem yes,it work..thanks Expert System...I'm very appreciate your help,again,thank very much expert system...